# How can I extract the fractional portion of a number and output it onto the console?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, ieee-754, mips32

I'm fairly new to Assembly language and was confused on how I can truncate a floating point number and then use that integer to run the program. I currently am able to run the program just fine however, I can not get the program to truncate the floating point number entered and convert it into an integer. This is what I have so far.

```
    .data
Prompt: .asciiz "\n Please Input a value for N = "
Result: .asciiz "\nThe sum of the integers from 1 to N is "
FP_Run: .asciiz "\nYou have entered a floating point number. The number you entered will be truncated. "
Bye:    .asciiz "\n **** Adios Amigo - Have a good day****"
zeroAsFloat: .float 0.0
    .globl main
    .text
main: 
    li  $v0, 4  #system call code for Print String
    la  $a0, Prompt #load address of prompt into $a0
    syscall     #print the prompt message
    li  $v0, 6 #system call code for Read Integer
    syscall     #reads the value of N into $v0
    blez    $v0, End #branch to end if $v0 < = 0
    li  $t0, 0 #clear register $t0 to 0
    
    #Display message
    lwc1 $f0, zeroAsFloat
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, FP_Run
    syscall
    #Read user input
    li $v0, 6
    syscall
    #Display value
    li $v0, 2
    add.s $f12, $f0, $f4
    syscall
    
#Move the FP number into an integer register, NO CONVERSION
    mfc1    $t1, $f0
    srl     $t2, $t1, 23
#Subtract 127 to get the exponent
    addi    $s3, $t2, -127 #This is the exponent
#Get the fraction
    sll     $t4, $t1, 9 #Shift out exponent and sign bit
    srl     $t5, $t4, 9 #Shift back to original position
    addi    $t6, $t5, 8388608 #add the implied bit to bit (2^23)
    addi    $t7, $s3, 9 #add 9 to the exponent
    sllv    $s4, $t6, $t7 #By Shifting to the left 9 + exponent
#Now get the integer
    rol     $t4, $t6, $t7 #Rotate the bits left by $t7 to get the integer
#Shift left 31 -exp to zero out the other bits
    li  $t5,31
    sub $t2, $t5, $s3 #Shift value
    sllv    $t5, $t4, $t2 #Zero out the fraction part
    srlv    $s5, $t5, $t2 #reset integer bits Integer is in $s5
    move    $v0, $s5 #move the integer into v0
    
     li     $t0, 0 #zero out of t0
     blez   $t1, End 
    
Loop:
    add $t0, $t0, $v0 #sum of integers in register $t0
    addi    $v0, $v0, -1 #summing integers in reverse order
    bnez    $v0, Loop #branch to loop is $v0 is != 0
    
    li  $v0, 4 #system call code for Print String
    la  $a0, Result #load address of message into $a0
    syscall #print the string
    
    li  $v0, 1 #system call code for Print Integer
    move    $a0, $t0 #move value to be printed to $a0
    syscall #print sum of integers
    b   main #branch to main
    
End:    li  $v0, 4 #system call code for Print String
    la  $a0, Bye #load address of msg. into $a0
    syscall #print the string
    li  $v0, 10 #terminate program run and
    syscall #return control to system
```

Comment: As this is more an algorithmic question, you first could do the same say in java with [`Double.doubleToRawLongBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double))

Comment: @JoopEggen: Yes, but note that this is using single-precision floating point (`add.s` not `add.d`), so the whole IEEE binary32 bit-pattern fits in a 32-bit register.  But you don't necessarily need to do bit-manipulation at all, you could just use the hardware float->int conversion instruction, assuming there is one that does truncation.  (e.g. `x - (int)x` for `x` values that fit in the range of an `int`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes for good order: [`floatToIntRawBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits(float)).  I appreciate people coding binary formats & love assembly. However if there are only unclear points on the algorithm a question in python or java would get more answers.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Usually they have problems with both.  Although, if the querent wrote that code themselves instead of copying it somewhere (a common thing: finding something like what your homework needs and then asking SO to change it), it seems they don't have a problem implementing bit-manipulation of FP bit-patterns.  Still, you'd have to be careful how you phrase a Java question, or you're likely to get answers that use library functions.  C is a good language for this because at least you can easily compile to MIPS assembly (with `-fno-delayed-branch` etc. to be MARS-friendly)

Comment: @PeterCordes agreed, and thanks for the perspective. This question however is worthy an answer, though not from me.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Well maybe.  It has code, but the [mcve] doesn't say what [actually does happen when run](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). And it's not actually complete, the `End` label isn't defined anywhere, and IDK why it would be branching on the FP bit pattern being zero or having the sign-bit set.  (`blez`). The comments are also too low-level to describe *why* it's doing that sequence of manipulations to the bit-pattern. MIPS doesn't even have a hardware rotate instruction, and it's not clear to me why rotating at the end would give you an integer.  A comment just claims it does

Comment: I tried running it just for fun.  If I type in 1.75 (3 times since the code runs 3 FP-input system calls for no apparent reason), then eventually I get a `1` in `$s5` (and `$v0`).  If you subtract `1.0` from `1.75`, you'd get the fractional part as a float.  You could multiply it by 100 or something and then take the integer part of that, if you want the first 2 decimal digits.  In a float bit-pattern itself, the fractional part is the part of the mantissa below what you shift out to get an integer.  It represents a value in terms of `2^-n` times that part of the mantissa, so it's not decimal

Comment: So what format do you want to output it in?  As a fraction, like 1234 / 2048?  That would be easiest (to do with bit manipulation), and kind of interesting.

Comment: @PeterCordes a last remark. I hope that the questions are addressed to the OP. But you hit the main reason for my initial comment: dealing with two aspects at the same time is hard - though admirable - for a beginner.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Oh, did SO notify you about my further comments?  I intentionally omitted an @ because I was writing them to the OP.

Comment: It is indeed common to have question posts here that take code from some website and ask us to change it for their hw.  One key tell-phrase is along the lines of "this code works perfectly" ... but doesn't do what I want.